# Where to put the Set function in MySQL when i have a CTE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I wanted to create an index number where it will ad itself by 1 when there is a person on the departments.

My question is, where is the right position of the **Set** command if I have a CTE?

my syntax:

```
with cte as(select emp.emp_no, dep.dept_name from dept_emp emp
join departments dep
on emp.dept_no=dep.dept_no)
set @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0;
select
case
    when dept_name ="Finance" then (@r1:=@r1+1)
    when dept_name ="Development" then (@r2:=@r2+1)
    when dept_name ="Marketing" then (@r3:=@r3+1)
    when dept_name ="Production" then (@r4:=@r4+1) 
    end as rownums,
case when dept_name ="Finance" then emp_no end as "Finance",
case when dept_name ="Development" then emp_no end as "Development",
case when dept_name ="Marketing" then emp_no end as "Marketing",
case when dept_name ="Production" then emp_no end as "Production"
from cte
```

Thank You

Comment: What is your intended result from this? Just to count the number of employees in each department?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  If you are using `with` then you are using MySQL 8+ and setting variables in `SELECT` statements is deprecated -- you shouldn't be doing it.  There are no doubt much simpler ways to do what you want.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with the appropriate information.

Answer (score 0):

SET must be placed into the rowsource:

```sql
with cte as(select emp.emp_no, dep.dept_name from dept_emp emp
join departments dep
on emp.dept_no=dep.dept_no)
/* set @r1=0, @r2=0, @r3=0, @r4=0; */ -- wrong place
select
case
    when dept_name ="Finance" then (@r1:=@r1+1)
    when dept_name ="Development" then (@r2:=@r2+1)
    when dept_name ="Marketing" then (@r3:=@r3+1)
    when dept_name ="Production" then (@r4:=@r4+1) 
    end as rownums,
case when dept_name ="Finance" then emp_no end as "Finance",
case when dept_name ="Development" then emp_no end as "Development",
case when dept_name ="Marketing" then emp_no end as "Marketing",
case when dept_name ="Production" then emp_no end as "Production"
from cte
-- put variables init there
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r1:=0, @r2:=0, @r3:=0, @r4:=0) AS init_vars
```

Pay attention - assignement operator `:=`, not assignement/compare `=` must be used.